# angularjs : I have one form it has many fields some of them carrying array to display dropdown. is it wise that we should provider?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

I have one form which has 10 to 12 fields which contains dropdown and multi select drop down. I want before my controller function gets called all the fields should filled up. I tried something like this :

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.config(function ($provide) {
    var transactionType = [
        { id: 0, type: 'card', value: 'card' },
        { id: 1, type: 'cash', value: 'cash' },
        { id: 2, type: 'other', value: 'other' }
    ];

    var friends = [
        { id: 0, name: 'A', value: 'A' },
        { id: 1, name: 'B', value: 'B' },
        { id: 2, name: 'C', value: 'C' },
        { id: 3, name: 'D', value: 'D' }
    ];

    var currency = [
        { id: 0, currency: 'USD', value: 'USD' },
        { id: 0, currency: 'INR', value: 'INR' },
        { id: 0, currency: 'EUR', value: 'EUR' },
    ];

    $provide.value('TransactionType', transactionType);
    $provide.value('Friends', friends);
    $provide.value('Currency', currency);
});

app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, TransactionType, Friends, Currency) {

});
```

Is this the right way considering that may be in future I have to use http service to get array from DB and to populate on dropdown list?

Comment: You should use the `resolve` feature of your router (ngRoute or ui-router).

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a specific type of provider called a Factory instead. If you use promises in your factory when switch to http services you'd only need to change your factory code - the rest of your application will work without code changes!

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .factory('Friend', function ($q) {    
    return {
      list: function() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        deferred.resolve([
          { id: 0, name: 'A', value: 'A' },
          { id: 1, name: 'B', value: 'B' },
          { id: 2, name: 'C', value: 'C' },
          { id: 3, name: 'D', value: 'D' }
        ]);

        return deferred.promise;
      }
    };
  });
```